# How to tell if obj is jquery or plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a stupid question but is there a way to tell programmatically if the object is jquery or just plain javascript?

For example:

```
Utils.Listbox.MoveItemsUp = function(listbox) {

    if(listbox.isJquery()) {
        listbox.each(function(){}); 
    }
    else {
        for(var i = 0; i < listbox.options.length; i++){}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery objects have a property called 'jquery':

```
>>> $('body').jquery
"1.5.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery *is* just Javascript. I guess you could test for the existence of a jQuery function though:

```
if (foo.each)
{
    foo.each(function(...
}
else
{
    $(foo).each(function(...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use jQuerys `$.isPlainObject` function ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/)) That will tell you if it was an object created using `{}` or `new Object`, a jQuery object will return false. However, note also that an array, and string and functions will also return false:

```
var obj = {};
var $obj = $('div');

$.isPlainObject(obj); //returns true
$.isPlainObject($obj); //returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should remember is that whenever your within a callback the object `this` is always an native entity and not a jquery object.

for example:

```
a = $('a').each(function(){
    //'this' is ALWAYS an native object
});
```

`a` will always be an instance of jQuery unless your using a specific method that returns a type such as json object, boolean, string etc.

if your recurving variable from a function that's out of your control and you want to know if it's a jQuery object you can do the following:

```
if(!listbox || !listbox.jquery)
{
     listbox = $(listbox)
}
//the variable is now always going to be a jQuery object.
```

the reason for this is that jquery always stores an reference to its version within a selected context

Answer (score 0):

To test if an object is a jQuery object, you check the `jquery` attribute of it.  so:

```
<script>
Utils.Listbox.isJquery = function()
{
    return typeof this.jquery != 'undefined';
}
</script>
```